# Augmented reality video play with transparent background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, augmented-reality

I am new in Augmented reality. What I needed is When my ipad app read any bar codes then it play a Transparent [video like](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juOPp21MnWI&feature=related).  I need to show catwalk of a modal.  My question what framework provide video rendering with AR. How can I achieve this. I have read about below Frameworks.

1) ar.qualcomm.at
2) ARToolKit

Comment: Even I looked for both of the framework and agreed upon working with  Qualcomm.Finally what was yours and can you help me to achieve since the same thing I am looking to develop.

Comment: The project was in estimation phase... we did not star work for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below framework, just sign for partnership (it is free) and simple to use.

[Aurasma](http://www.aurasma.com/)

Comment: Thanks Muhammad for response. But i needed public API and Aurasma doesn't have any API or framework it is a AR  application it self.

Comment: they actually have a framework, just request developer access & you will get access to there API :)

Comment: OK, I drop a email for the same. because web site is not showing any information for the same. Ill check your Ans once get successes. For now +1 for quick response